# Icon setting in shortcut in android

Tags: android, json, android-drawable, shortcut, url-parameters

When create shortcut icon to app in general:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getActivity(), R.drawable.icon));
```

but I want to bring on the Web and use `R.drawable.icon` instead of `http://~~~~~.png`. How should I do it?